# How to change state in componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react page and based upon an `Axios` call failure, I set error `state` to true which is false by default. When its `true`, I show an error. I tried to use `componentDidMount` for that as below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const showError = this.state.saveError;
  if(showError) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        saveError: false
      })
    }, 3000)
  }
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work as the error is always displayed once set to true. How do I fix it? Any other suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Should it not be `componentDidUpdate`? You initialize component and its rendered. Post that componentDidMount will not be called.

Comment: Ah yes.. correct. Let me do that. Been sometime using those.

Comment: Add that as answer.

Comment: Why would you need lifecycle methods for that purpose? Doesn't conditional rendering of error message based on state do the trick for you?

Comment: I was trying to use react-loading-overlay hence needed something from state. But its does not looks good. Trying to find an alternative for error message on center of screen.

Answer (score 1):

Update the state in `componentDidUpdate` as the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method will execute whenever there is an update in component.

**Sample Code:**

```
 componentDidUpdate() {
    const showError = this.state.saveError;
    if (showError) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
                return {
                    ...prevState 
                    saveError: false
                }
            })
        }, 3000)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show your initialState. Please explain what are you trying to do here, because I don't see any Axios request.

Assign value of state to variable doesn't make any sense:
`const showError = this.state.saveError;`